# Criar matriz de distribuição de frequências no R (variável categórica VS numérica)

Tags: r, matriz

Tenho duas colunas: situação da oferta (variável categórica) e nº de alunos (variável numérica). Desejo criar uma tabela que informe quantos alunos estão em cada modalidade (classe/levels). O objetivo é esse (exemplo):

[image: Distribuição de Frequência (situação da oferta x nº de alunos) EXEMPLO]

Desde já agradeço,
PS: Ao me ajudar nesse trabalho, você ajudará a expansão de inovações como o Stack Over Flow na educação pública (este é a minha área de estudo).

Comment: O que voce já fez até então? Nós ajudamos corrigir erros...

Comment: Obrigado pela participação, Renaro! Desculpe-me, sou novo aqui e tentei usar o máximo da minha objetividade. Bom, aqui está uma das minhas tentativas:                                                > setwd("C:/R")
> library(car)
> UABalunos<- read.csv ("C:/R/UAB.Alunos_por_polos2014.csv", header=TRUE, dec="." , sep=";")
> UAB<-data.frame(UABalunos)
> situacao<-factor(UAB$no_situacao_oferta_41)
> oferta<-(UAB$oferta_numero_alunos_cadastrados_42)
> sitvsof<-table(UAB$situacao, UAB$oferta)
> sitvsof
< table of extent 0 x 0 >

Comment: escreva o que voce fez junto com a resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou criar um `data.frame` de exemplo assim:

```
library(dplyr)
base <- data.frame(
  situacao = rep(c("a ser concluida", "ativa", "concluida"), length.out = 100),
  qtd_alunos = rep(c(6,7,2,3), length.out = 100)
  )

> head(base)
         situacao qtd_alunos
1 a ser concluida          6
2           ativa          7
3       concluida          2
4 a ser concluida          3
5           ativa          6
6       concluida          7
```

Você pode em seguida agregar a `qtd_alunos` pelas categorias da variável `situacao` usando:

```
base %>% group_by(situacao) %>% summarise(qtd_alunos = sum(qtd_alunos))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

         situacao qtd_alunos
1 a ser concluida        153
2           ativa        151
3       concluida        146
```

O comando `group_by` indica qual é a variável que você deseja usar para agregar e o comando `summarise` indica como você quer agregar/sumarisar a informação, no caso usamos a soma.

Se cada aluno for uma linha da sua base de dados, e você não possuir a coluna `qtd_alunos`, você poderia usar o código a seguir para criar uma tabela de frequências:

```
base %>% group_by(situacao) %>% summarise(qtd_alunos = n())
```

Nesse caso especifico usando o comando `n()` que quero contar o número de linhas por categoria.

Note que para ter as funções `group_by`e `summarise`é preciso ter o pacote dplyr instalado: `install.packages("dplyr")` e depois carregá-lo `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Não tenho reputação para votar a favor, mas saiba que a sua resposta foi muito boa! Parabéns pela qualidade e rapidez, agora sou um entusiasta do stackoverflow. Muito obrigado!